# Azure SQL Elastic scaling: What happens to active queries while scaling down?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Will active queries keep going on the old service level and the scaling wait for all active connections to drop, or will they be disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contained database users connected to the database will stay connected while scale up/down the tier, but server logins will be disconnected during that process and open transactions will be rolled back.